# Getting 502 Bad Gateway Error in CloudFront AWS while using SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to use Cloudfront for the first time.
Here is my infrastructure:

- Created an alias (CNAME in OVH) from my domain name to the cloudfront domaine name
- I have a cloudfront distribution deployed with the following configuration (see below)
- I'm using an EC2 custom origin, in where I have installed Nginx (reverse-proxy) accepting traffic on port 443(https) and redirecting traffic of port 80(http) to 443(https)
- I'm using a valid SSL certificate (until Sept 2018) that I created using letsencrypt and uploaded it to ACM (cert.pem -> Body / privkey.pem -> Private key / fullchain.pem -> chain`)
- In Nginx I'm referencing the fullchain.pem and the privkey.pem

Here is my configuration
[image: CloudFrontConfig1]
[image: CloudFrontConfig2]

While troubleshooting I have done the following:

- Used an SSL checker (https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker) which tells me that the certificate and the chain were find but not the root. BTW other online SSL checkers say that everything is ok. Don't know if the issue is coming from here. Amazon CM finds that the private, certificate and the chain are OK.
- Used Openssl

`openssl s_client –connect domainname:443 –servername domainname`
`openssl s_client –connect domainname:443`

The first command is ok but the second is giving me SSL HANDSHAKE ERROR. 
But Cloudfront is not configured to allow non SNI clients. So I think it is ok
 - Checked my domaine with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for ciphers & protocols. Everything seem to be ok. I can give more details if necessary

I'm still getting:

> "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin."

[image: CloudFrontConfig3]

Any help please?

thank you

Comment: Under "Cache based on selected request headers," choose Whitelist and add the `Host` header.

Comment: That does not work. Just for follow up, I think that I have found the root cause which is the fact that my origin domain name (ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com) is not the one for which the certificate was issued for. Moreover, letsencrypt does not allow to issue a certificate for EC2 custom domain names. Don't know what to do :(

Comment: Yes, that's the root of the issue, but if you install that same certificate on nginx and whitelist the `Host` header, CloudFront should still allow it... but nginx needs to respond with that certificate without a SNI match (e.g. it needs to be your origin's default cert).

Comment: `true | openssl s_client –connect ec2-xxx.compute...com:443 –servername ec2-xxx.compute...com -showcerts | openssl x509 -text -noout` to verify that the correct cert is used... and the "correct" cert means the one matching your actual domain.

Comment: the issue is that I'm not able to generate a certificate for my ec2-xxx.compute...com domain name. Here is why: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6nvy4j/how_to_have_https_ssl_cert_on_an_ec2_public_dns/

Comment: I fully understand that.  The "correct" cert you should see when connecting directly to your instance is the one for your domain.  The same one that is installed in CloudFront.